# Issue in writing from SAP HANA Vora to SAP HANA

Tags: vora

I am trying to write data from HANA Vora to HANA.

I used the code as in HANA academy ,  https://github.com/saphanaacademy/Vora/blob/master/Vora_Writing2HANA.txt

However I get error , when I execute the below line :

hana_datardd.write.format("com.sap.spark.hana").mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).options(HANA_LOAD_OPTIONS).save()

The error says “error: not found: value SaveMode “

Below is the screen shot of the error.

[Hana Vora writing to HANA error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2dwJU.png)

Please can me guide me on writing data from HANA Vora to HANA.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import SaveMode

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SaveMode
```